# Compare two date object in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to compare two date objects in angular 4 but it always returning false

below are my code snippet

```
CheckForHoliday(d: Date) {
  let simpleDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay());
  let hDate = new Date(2018, 9, 1);
  console.log(simpleDate + "==========" + hDate);
  console.log(hDate === simpleDate);

  return (hDate === simpleDate);
}
```

The output is as below

*Mon Oct 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)==========Mon Oct 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)*

*false*

Any Idea why it returning false when the printed values look same?

Comment: Include MomentJS into your application if you can and use the isSame function to compare.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a date.getTime() and then compare the two numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the dates in the date Objects. If you call the getDate() method on the date Objects you will get true.

```
hDate.getDate() === simpleDate.getDate() //=> returns true
```

Comment: That's incorrect. [`Date.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) returns the day of the month.

Comment: Indeed missed that, my bad, Date.toString() or Date.getTime() should do the trick;

Comment: Yes or even better, `Date.getTime()` (no need to compare string representations when you can compare the inner timestamps).

Answer (score 0):

`new Date` will return an object and you cannot compare objects like that. Try converting both of them to string before comparing them.

Do it like this

```
CheckForHoliday(d: Date) {
  let simpleDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay());
  let hDate = new Date(2018, 9, 1);
  console.log(simpleDate + "==========" + hDate);
  console.log(hDate === simpleDate);

  return (hDate.toString() === simpleDate.toString());
}
```